# Delete confirmation in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project in django. I have this part of code, when I want to delete an album, it shows Yes or No to choose, but the problem is, whatever the choice I make, it always delete the album. I know I have to add something to the confirmation option but I don't want where or what.

```
<form action="{% url 'music:delete_album' album.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{ album.id }}" />
                                <button type="submit" onclick="confirm('Are you sure ?')" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
```

and this is the delete_album view :

```
def delete_album(request, album_id):
    album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
    album.delete()
    albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'albums': albums})
```

Comment: the javascript confirm() method returns a boolean value. you should submit the form only if it returns true.

Comment: and how do I do that ?

Comment: try this: remove the confirm() from where you have it now and put it up in the form:  <form onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">

Comment: It works :D thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It could be validated before to submit your form. If you copy the next snipped then It will validate :)

```
<form action="{% url 'music:delete_album' album.id %}" 
    method="post" style="display: inline;" onsubmit="window.mytest()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="album_id" 
        value="{{ album.id }}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">window.mytest = function() { var isValid = confirm('Are you sure ?');if (!isValid) { event.preventDefault();  alert("It wont delete. Yay!");}}</script>
```

Comment: Hello. I want to do the delete method without having to do the confirmation message in DeleteView ?

Comment: If you are talking about the template you just delete onsubmit from <form> and tag script too.